# IdentityServer4 multiple user types

Tags: authentication, identity, multi-tenant, identityserver4

We are building a web app (Angular frontend + Asp net core) in which we have 2 different kinds of users.

1) The merchant

2) The customers

The idea is that (a bit like deliveroo) customers can pick some stuff from different merchants and add them to their basket.

What we want is a frontend app for the customers and another app for the merchants to manage their account.
We are currently using IdentityServer4 and the question is: do we need to serve 2 instances of IdentityServer, 1 for customers and 1 for merchants? Or do we need to store all of them in the same database? Then use something like multitenancy?

Comment: The distinction sounds very much like a `Role`.The users of your system can have one of two different roles: either a merchant or a customer. You may, or may not, choose to have have two different apps (aka clients) or just manage both roles through one client.

Comment: @marayfirth have you found your way?

Comment: I'm still working on it. The point is, I didn't want to reimplement all the identity logic. I wanted to have the unique key to be {username, usertype} instead of just username (defined by identity). That's a constraint a role can't really handle, at least at database level (or does it?). So I started softly after reading this: https://www.scottbrady91.com/ASPNET-Identity/Quick-and-Easy-ASPNET-Identity-Multitenancy. I've added a TenantId like column and it seems ok for user registration. Thanks for your advice :)

Comment: @marayfirth marking answer build your reputation and answer-er as well :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Introducing IdentityServer4 for authentication ..](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/09/19/introducing-identityserver4-for-authentication-and-access-control-in-asp-net-core/) posted by Brock Allen and Dominick Baier.

> Modern applications need modern identity. The protocols used for
>   implementing features like authentication, single sign-on, API access
>   control and federation are OpenID Connect and OAuth 2.0.
>   IdentityServer is a popular open source framework for implementing
>   authentication, single sign-on and API access control using ASP.NET.

Not sure why you think you need two identity server, but my understanding is you should have one IdServer that will server to multiple clients. Two apps merchant and customer is nothing but Client according to IdentityServer.

You can use userclaim to allow users to access restricted actions. You may have two roles Customer or Merchant etc. And add authorization policy if you have different access level in one app. But for two different app you can have different Client with Different scopes that you need to define on your app configuration

You can also multi-tenancy supports by adding a user claim e.g. TenantId. In that case, if you use asp.net identity then you need to customise your context.